# PySpark - Count distinct by row and column

Tags: python, pyspark

Could you please suggest how to count distinct values for the following case.

I have dataframe in PySpark (columns: 'Rank', 'Song', 'Artist', 'Year', 'Lyrics', 'Source'). The column "Lyrics" contains string values and should be divided by words.

[image: Dataframe]

I've already calculated the number of all words for each row in the column "Lyrics". I also converted strings to lists saving the result in a new column "uniqWords_count". Unfortunately, I can't figure it out how to devote and count distinct values.

Here's the code if it might be useful:

```
billdf = billdf.withColumn('allWords_count', f.size(f.split(f.col('Lyrics'), ' ')))

billdf = billdf.withColumn('uniqWords_count', f.split(f.col('Lyrics'), ' '))
```

Tried to apply countDistinct function, but it resulted in the error:

```
billdf = billdf.withColumn('uniqWords_count', f.countDistinct(f.split(f.col('Lyrics'), ' ')))
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3784.withColumn.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`Song`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(count(DISTINCT split(`Lyrics`, ' ', -1)) AS `uniqWords_count`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`Song`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

Comment: To get count of unique words, do `F.size(F.array_distinct("arraycolumn"))`. will work for **`spark2.4`**.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10107389/mohammad-murtaza-hashmi) has suggested a solution. 
In my case it looks like this:

```
billdf = billdf.withColumn('uniqWords',f.size(f.array_distinct("uniqWords")))
```

Thanks very much for help!